# How can I execute a sql script file from msi installer(c#)?

Tags: c#

I know this question had been posted by a few others. But my question is, I would like to execute a sql script file from the installer which I created. I found some information related to my question in some forum that says, the sql script file can be executed through a batch file. That batch can be executed using the process class in c#.

Can anyone show me how to execute a sql script from the installer without going through the batch file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Process.Start() to kick off OSQL.exe with command-line parameters that point to your .SQL file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Microsoft sql server, then to execute sql script as part of msi installation, check this [link](http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.com/2008/08/executing-sqlcmd-from-wix.html).